# nav_graph argument error due to ModelClass is not a Serializable or Parcelable in KotlinMultiplatform App

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, kmm

I was developing an KotlinMultiplatform App which implement diferents libraries as NavigationComponent, ktor to networks call, and slqDelight to store local data.

So the error I'm getting in the  tag is the following:

```
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.jshvarts.kmp.android:navigation/nav_graph line 23


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.jshvarts.kmp.model.UnsplashPhoto is not Serializable or Parcelable.
```

Regarding this line is the argument which I'd like to pass between screens:

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.jshvarts.kmp.android.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigate_from_home_to_detail"
            app:destination="@+id/detailFragment">
        </action>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.jshvarts.kmp.android.detail.DetailFragment"
        android:label="DetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail">
    <argument
        android:name="photo"
        app:argType="com.jshvarts.kmp.model.UnsplashPhoto"
        />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And regarding my model class:

UnsplashPhoto.kt

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class UnsplashPhoto(
  @SerialName("id") val id: String?,
  @SerialName("description") var description: String?,
  @SerialName("urls") val urls: UnsplashPhotoUrls,
  @SerialName("user") val user: UnsplashUser
)

@Serializable
data class UnsplashPhotoUrls(
  @SerialName("raw") val raw: String,
  @SerialName("full") val full: String,
  @SerialName("regular") val regular: String,
  @SerialName("small")  val small: String,
  @SerialName("thumb")  val thumb: String
)

private val defaultUsername = "username"

@Serializable
data class UnsplashUser(
  @SerialName("name") val name: String,
  @SerialName("username") val username: String = defaultUsername,
  @SerialName("attributionUrl") val attributionUrl:String = "https://unsplash.com/$defaultUsername?utm_source=ImageSearchApp&utm_medium=referral"
)
```

and finally my build.gradle.kts files of shared, android, and proyect module:

build.gradle.kts(androidApp)

```
plugins {
  //kotlin(multiplatform)
  id("com.android.application")
  kotlin("android")
  kotlin("kapt")
  id("kotlinx-serialization")
  id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdk)

  compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions{
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
  }

  kapt{
    generateStubs = true
    correctErrorTypes = true
  }

  buildFeatures{
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.jshvarts.kmp.android"
    minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdk)
    targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdk)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
      isMinifyEnabled = false
      proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
  implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8", Versions.kotlin))
  implementation(Coroutines.android)
  implementation(AndroidX.appCompat)
  implementation(AndroidX.constraintLayout)
  implementation(AndroidX.recyclerView)
  implementation(AndroidX.lifecycleExtensions)
  implementation(AndroidX.lifecycleViewModelKtx)
  implementation(material)
  implementation(AndroidX.swipeToRefreshLayout)
  implementation(timber)
  implementation(picasso)
  implementation(AndroidX.navigation)
  implementation(AndroidX.navigation_ui)
  implementation(Serialization.runtime)
  //Dependency for googlePay
  implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1")
  kapt(databinding)
  implementation(glide){
    exclude( "com.android.support")
  }
  kapt(glide)
  implementation(project(":shared"))

}
```

build.gradle.kts(shared)

```
plugins {
  id("com.android.library")
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  id("kotlinx-serialization")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods")
  id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}
// CocoaPods requires the podspec to have a version.
version = "1.0"

android {
  compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdk)
  buildToolsVersion(Versions.androidBuildTools)

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdk)
    targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdk)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
  }
}
version = "1.0"
dependencies {
  implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1")
}

kotlin {
  targets {

    val sdkName: String? = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")

    val isiOSDevice = sdkName.orEmpty().startsWith("iphoneos")
    if (isiOSDevice) {
      iosArm64("iOS")
    } else {
      iosX64("iOS")
    }
    android()
  }

  cocoapods {
    // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
    summary = "Description for a Kotlin/Native module"
    homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
  }

  sourceSets {
    all {
      languageSettings.apply {
        useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi")
      }
    }

    val commonMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.common)
        implementation(SqlDelight.runtime)
        implementation(Serialization.runtime)
        //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${Versions.kotlin}")
        //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${Versions.kotlin}")
        //implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1")
      }
    }

    val commonTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.jvm)
      }
    }

    val androidMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.android)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.slf4j)
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.jvm)
        implementation(Serialization.runtime)
        implementation(SqlDelight.android)


      }
    }

    val androidTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.common)
      }
    }

    val iOSMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.ios)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.jvm)
       // implementation(Serialization.runtimeNative)
        implementation(SqlDelight.runtime)
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.common)
      }
    }

    val iOSTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.native)
      }
    }
  }
}


sqldelight {
  database("PetsDatabase") {
    packageName = "com.jshvarts.kmp.db"
    sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
  }
}
```

build.gradle.kts(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath(kotlin("serialization", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:${Versions.sqldelight}")
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.28.0")
        classpath ("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:${Versions.navigation}")


        //classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")
        //classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")
        //classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-parcelize-runtime:${Versions.kotlin}")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

//TODO("Probar bajando a kotlin version 1.3.72, y habilitando el android-extensions")
plugins {
  //kotlin("jvm") version "${Versions.kotlin}"
  id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "9.2.1"
  id ("com.github.ben-manes.versions") version "0.28.0"
  //kotlin("android") version "${Versions.kotlin}" apply false
  //id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize") version "${Versions.kotlin}"
}
apply(from = "quality/lint.gradle")
```

So I guess i can't create a Serializable object like this, or i have some library incompablity which made my Serialization objects unreadable, but how should I do?

Thank in advance !

[EDIT]

Added the build.gradle.kts(androidApp)

```
plugins {
  //kotlin(multiplatform)
  id("com.android.application")
  kotlin("android")
  kotlin("kapt")
  id("kotlinx-serialization")
  id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdk)

  compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions{
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
  }

  kapt{
    generateStubs = true
    correctErrorTypes = true
  }

  buildFeatures{
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.jshvarts.kmp.android"
    minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdk)
    targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdk)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
      isMinifyEnabled = false
      proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
  implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8", Versions.kotlin))
  implementation(Coroutines.android)
  implementation(AndroidX.appCompat)
  implementation(AndroidX.constraintLayout)
  implementation(AndroidX.recyclerView)
  implementation(AndroidX.lifecycleExtensions)
  implementation(AndroidX.lifecycleViewModelKtx)
  implementation(material)
  implementation(AndroidX.swipeToRefreshLayout)
  implementation(timber)
  implementation(picasso)
  implementation(AndroidX.navigation)
  implementation(AndroidX.navigation_ui)
  implementation(Serialization.runtime)
  //Dependency for googlePay
  implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1")
  kapt(databinding)
  implementation(glide){
    exclude( "com.android.support")
  }
  kapt(glide)
  implementation(project(":shared"))

}
```

Comment: have you add navigation fragment dependcy as well it is related to this

Comment: I edit the post adding the build.grald.kts of androidApp, where I apply the navigation plugin on classpath and implements the naviation libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are mixing dependencies, you are using the `kotlinx.serialization.Serializable` and the one you need is the `java.io.Serializable`.

There's no annotation available for the last one, so you can go ahead and do this instead:

```
@Serializable
data class UnsplashPhoto(
  @SerialName("id") val id: String?,
  @SerialName("description") var description: String?,
  @SerialName("urls") val urls: UnsplashPhotoUrls,
  @SerialName("user") val user: UnsplashUser
): java.io.Serializable
```

That should do the trick.
(You can keep the json Serializable annotation if you will be using it later)

Comment: But I'm still have to import @SerialName from kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

Comment: Actually, this implementation doesn't work

Comment: Did you also add the java.io.Serializable to the other Unsplash data classes you have?